# Move the cursor to IBAction of control in Xcode

Tags: xcode, keyboard-shortcuts

Suppose I am in the Assistant Editor mode of Xcode and I click on a UIButton. Is there a way to jump to the IBAction associated with the UIButton in code editor side of the IDE?